# Select date dynamically in the calendar using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to use selenium to do an automation where I login to the page, click on the side menu and enter the page where I want. This part of the code is working correctly. The issue is that I need to interact with the calendars that are on the page, giving the option for the user to choose which date he wants to pull the report. But in my code somehow both calendars are being filled with the current date.
And also even with the current date the excel file is coming empty after clicking the generate button. How can I fix these errors?

```
import datetime
import time
import os
import pandas as pd
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pyautogui

data_inicial_escolha = input("Digite a primeira data (no formato YYYY-MM-DD): ")
data_final_escolha = input("Digite a segunda data (no formato YYYY-MM-DD): ")

data_1_str = str(data_inicial_escolha)
data_2_str = str(data_final_escolha)

data_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(data_1_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
data_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(data_2_str, "%Y-%m-%d")

dia_1 = data_1.day
mes_1 = data_1.month
ano_1 = data_1.year

dia_2 = data_2.day
mes_2 = data_2.month
ano_2 = data_2.year

data_formatada_1 = data_1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
data_formatada_2 = data_2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# Configuração do Selenium
servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
navegador.implicitly_wait(10)  # Tempo de espera implícito

# Fazer login
navegador.get("myurl")
campo_usuario = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-input-0"]')
campo_usuario.send_keys("user")
campo_senha = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-input-1"]')
campo_senha.send_keys("password")
campo_botao = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]')
campo_botao.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(navegador, 10)
wait.until(EC.url_contains("myurl2"))

relatorios_link = navegador.find_element(By.ID, 'mat-expansion-panel-header-2')  # naq
relatorios_link.click()

pedidos_status = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='myurl2']")
pedidos_status.click()

calendario_um = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-root/app-back-office/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/app-ecred/app-reports/app-report-status/form/app-datepicker[1]/div/mat-form-field/div/div[1]/div[2]')
calendario_um.click()
pyautogui.typewrite(f"{data_formatada_1}\n")

calendario_dois = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-root/app-back-office/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/app-ecred/app-reports/app-report-status/form/app-datepicker[2]/div/mat-form-field/div/div[1]/div[2]/mat-datepicker-toggle/button')
calendario_dois.click()
pyautogui.typewrite(f"{data_formatada_2}\n")

botao_gerar = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-root/app-back-office/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/app-ecred/app-reports/app-report-status/form/div/button[1]')
botao_gerar.click()

time.sleep(10)
tabela = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/app-root/app-back-office/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/app-ecred/app-reports/app-report-status/app-table")
linhas = tabela.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
dados = []

for linha in linhas:
    colunas = linha.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    if len(colunas) >= 5: 
        consume_cpf = colunas[0].text
        consumer_name = colunas[1].text
        consumer_phone = colunas[2].text
        created_at = colunas[3].text
        id = colunas[4].text

        dados.append([consume_cpf, consumer_name, consumer_phone, created_at, id])
df = pd.DataFrame(dados)

diretorio_atual = os.getcwd()
nome_arquivo = "dados6.xlsx"
caminho_arquivo = os.path.join(diretorio_atual, nome_arquivo)
df.to_excel(caminho_arquivo, index=False)
print("Arquivo Excel gerado com sucesso!")
```